# How can I ignore the contents of /proc directory from the output of ls -lR command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I just want to list all the files in the system by using ls -lR command . But I don't want the /proc directory and its sub directories to be listed because they are not useful for me.
  But when I do **ls -lR --ignore proc /** . It ignores all the files names proc even if they are outside the proc directory. **ls -lR --ignore /proc /** also doesn't work. Is there any way around?

Comment: `find` would be a good option in this case as it has provide more options. Any reason why you are stuck with `ls` and cannot consider `find`?

Comment: Yeah I think I should use find , that will me more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ls` with `extglob` for this:

```
shopt -s extglob

ls -lR -I proc@(/*|)
```

Extended glob pattern `proc@(/*|)` matches `proc` directory and all the children of `proc` directory.

Comment: It is still showing all the proc files and its sub directories.

Comment: Make sure you run `shopt` command as shown here. I have tested it and it doesn't show `proc` directory and it's content.

Comment: No it didn't. It is still traversing proc directory.

Comment: What is your bash version? It works for me on bash bash version 4.4.12

Comment: My bash version is 4.4.30.

Comment: Visit this link to execute bash script online: https://www.jdoodle.com/test-bash-shell-script-online and enter this code: `cd /var/; shopt -s extglob; ls -lR -I cache@(/*|)` This will list all files inside `/var` except skipping `/var/cache/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use grep with -v option

```
ls -lR / | grep -v /proc
```

Comment: grep -v /proc  also ingnores all the directories named proc not only the root one.